# How to stipulate a range of years using the date field type in doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I need a date drop down in a Symfony2 site form, and am using the 'date' field type in my form builder. Here is my declaration:

```
$builder->add('date', 'date', array(
   'label' => 'Date',
   'format' => 'dd MM yyyy',
   'required' => true
));
```

By default this will display 5 years in the past and 5 years in the future (i.e. 2010 - 2020) but I need it to start from this year and only show a couple of years in the future, as for this particular form there is no need for a past date or a date too far in the future.

I read in the Doctrine documentation that you can list a range of years, but how I get it to automatically use THIS year and then a couple of years in the future?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can format it using the `years` option:

```
$builder->add('date', 'date', array(
   'label' => 'Date',
   'format' => 'dd MM yyyy',
   'years' => range(date('Y'), date('Y') + 5),
   'required' => true
));
```

SF docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#years

Comment: Does it work in Symfony3? It seems it does not, I get   _An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion") in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 60._

Comment: As you can see, you're getting the error in the layout, so the issue is somewhere else. The docs that I've linked are the current, so 3.x is ok.

Comment: it works on 3.1. It was a mistake on my side, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **years** instead **year**
it works like that for me.

```
$builder->add('date', 'date', array(
   'label' => 'Date',
   'years' => range(date('Y'), date('Y') + 10),
   'required' => true
));
```

Or specified date, 
 for example between 1990 and today:

```
$builder->add('date', 'date', array(
       'label' => 'Date',
       'years' => range(date('1990'), date('Y')),
       'required' => true
    ));
```

Symfony 2, Doctrine 2.4.8